# How to assign variable in ‘Headers'

Tags: powerquery, m

I have Report where the dates are as column headers.

The report is set as "show last x weeks" so each week the date should shift by 7 days, but it causes an issue down the line as PowerQuery fixes the header name as a constant into the code and does not update accordingly.

So this week report should start with 10/12/18 date range and end with 11/02/19.

```
 = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Project 
Location Name", "Role Name", "03/12/2018", "10/12/2018",
"17/12/2018", "24/12/2018", "31/12/2018", "07/01/2019", "14/01/2019",
"21/01/2019", "28/01/2019", "04/02/2019", "Total"}, {"Project Location
Name", "Role Name", "03/12/2018", "10/12/2018", "17/12/2018",
"24/12/2018", "31/12/2018", "07/01/2019", "14/01/2019", "21/01/2019",
"28/01/2019", "04/02/2019", "Total"})
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use Control-K to format your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this might be by changing this line:

```
Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Project Location Name", "Role Name", "03/12/2018", "10/12/2018", "17/12/2018", "24/12/2018", "31/12/2018", "07/01/2019", "14/01/2019", "21/01/2019", "28/01/2019", "04/02/2019", "Total"}, {"Project Location Name", "Role Name", "03/12/2018", "10/12/2018", "17/12/2018", "24/12/2018", "31/12/2018", "07/01/2019", "14/01/2019", "21/01/2019", "28/01/2019", "04/02/2019", "Total"})
```

to:

```
let
    headersToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Converted to Table"[Column1], Record.FieldNames))),
    expandDynamically = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", headersToExpand)
in
    expandDynamically
```

Assuming:

- every row in `"Column1"` contains `records`,
- your previous "step" is `#"Converted to Table"`,
- the column of records (that you want to expand) is called `"Column1"`,

then the `headersToExpand` bit should give you a `list` of unique record field names (rather than the hard coded `list` you had) -- which can then be used in the `expandDynamically` step.